# Spring MVC disable handler registration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I don't want Spring MVC to register some of my controllers.

By reading the framework code, I found out that this registration is done in `initHandlerMethods` of `AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java`. Here it says that if the bean name starts with `SCOPED_TARGET_NAME_PREFIX` it is not registered.

Although this does what I want, `SCOPED_TARGET_NAME_PREFIX` is a private constant. Can I achieve the same thing in a more portable way?

Comment: sorry but do you want register a controller but don't expose the @RequestMapping or do you want that your controller is not registered?

Comment: I still want to use @RequestMapping, but I don't want spring to detect this.

Comment: um.... but this request is very strange. I mean if you use @RequestMapping on a method you are using it because you want expose it as end-point otherwise the best option for skip it on the pubblishing is don't annotated it

Comment: Why don't you use the real value of this private constant which is `scopedTarget.` since you believe this will achieve what you want?